# IRQ DMA error fills up dmesg

Tags: kernel

I recently upgraded to ubuntu 16.04 and my processor keeps running. I checked top and there's a kworker always running. I checked dmesg errors like the following keep be logged:

```
[329479.460021] nand: timeout while waiting for chip to become ready
[329479.860009] nand: timeout while waiting for chip to become ready
[329480.260009] nand: No NAND device found
[329480.260023] r852: detected SmartMedia readonly card in slot
[329480.524457] r592: IRQ: card added
[329480.524466] r592: IRQ: DMA error
[329480.604394] r592: IRQ: card added
[329480.604399] r592: IRQ: DMA error
...(stack trace)
```

Any idea of how I can trouble shoot this? I can't decipher the posts on launchpad.

edit:
It looks like here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1530187
So is there no fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I check dmesg, I still get these errors, but kworker isn't going crazy.

The problem for me was I has installed 64bit ubuntu instead of 32bit ubuntu.

oye vey!

Comment: I don't think this is a solution. Can happen even when the architecture is correct

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this same problem too. It seems this bug is related to Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter. A possible workaround is blacklisting the module if you don't use the Card Reader a lot.

Create a file in `/etc/modprobe.d/` with name `blacklist-r592.conf` and put this line in that file

```
blacklist r592
```

then restart the PC. The error should go away.

Alternatively, you can also use this two line instead (change the filename accordingly if you want) as suggested in this [bug report comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1500156/comments/38)

```
options r592 enable_dma=0
options r852 r852_enable_dma=0
```

But this is not tested by me.